# Interpolation of trigonometric functions

Tags: interpolation

I want to evaluate $f''(x)$ for $f(x)=\sin(x)$ and $x=\frac{\pi}{6}$ and then determine the error in the approximation of $f''(\frac{\pi}{6})$.

From previous knowledge, I know that to find an approximation, we need to compute the first derivative to represent the change. Since the question requires the second derivative, I'm a little confused. I appreciate any assistance.

Comment: Are you sure $f''=-f$ perhaps in Taylor series of $\sin$.

Comment: Yes. that is true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: $f^{"}(x)=-\sin x$.
Treat this as $y=f^{"}(x)$

Then simply $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$$

Hope it solves your problem?

Comment: Yes that clears the air thank you